# Why Adobe sensei recommended products don't show products?

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, magento2-cloud, adobe-sensei

I configured the Adobe Sensei Recommended products as the documentation said, then I navigated some minutes through many products and try to see some product in my recommendations, but just one shows up.

How could I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In non-production environments like testing or staging, there is often not much storefront behavioural data (unless automated) to serve Recommendations. Actual shopper behaviour at scale is captured only in the production environment.

So to see the Production environment data in your Staging environment, before you begin, make sure that:

- Storefront data collection is configured and enabled on production.
- Your non-production environment catalog is largely the same as the one that you have in production. Using similar catalogs ensures that the products returned in the recommendation units closely mimic those on production.

1. Launch your non-production environment.
2. On the Admin sidebar, go to **Marketing > Promotions > Product Recommendations**.
3. Select Settings.
4. In the Recommendations source section, enable the Fetch recommendations from a different SaaS environment option.
5. The Available SaaS Environments list appears.
6. Select the SaaS environment associated with your production environment or another environment that has shopper data you want to use.
7. Click Save changes.

Magento will now fetch recommendations from that environment.

[image: Magento Adobe Sensei]

> When recommendations from another SaaS environment are displayed on the storefront, a storefront user can only preview them (they are not clickable).

Reference: [Fetch Recommendations from different SaaS environment](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/recommendation-change-source.html#fetch-recommendations-from-different-saas-environment)